# Why an indexed array is not formed when fetching data in a Bolt CMS template

Tags: arrays, templates, twig, bolt-cms

In a twig Bolt CMS template, I am trying to create an array without duplicate values by fetching data from a table `Pillars` as follows:

```
{% set arr = [] %}
{% setcontent pillars = 'Pillars' %}
{% for pillar in pillars %}
{% if pillar.title not in arr %}
{% set arr = arr|merge([pillar.title]) %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ dump(arr) }}
```

The `if` condition does not seem to work because `arr` is not an indexed array. I would expect to get the following result (for example) from the `{{ dump(arr) }}`:

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "Cash Transfer"
  1 => "Human Resource"
  2 => "ICT Services"
]
```

But instead I get the following, with duplicate `Human Resource` values not removed:

```
array:5 [▼
  0 => Twig_Markup {#4297 ▼
    #content: "Cash Transfer"
    #charset: "UTF-8"
  }
  1 => Twig_Markup {#4294 ▼
    #content: "Human Resource"
    #charset: "UTF-8"
  }
  2 => Twig_Markup {#4530 ▼
    #content: "ICT Services"
    #charset: "UTF-8"
  }
  3 => Twig_Markup {#4527 ▼
    #content: "Human Resource"
    #charset: "UTF-8"
  }
  4 => Twig_Markup {#4523 ▼
    #content: "Human Resource"
    #charset: "UTF-8"
  }
]
```

What could be the problem or what could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The build index is not wrong actually. The `Twig_Markup` class just makes that the content inside is treated as safe. You just could do `{{ arr[1] }}` and it would output `Human resource`. The solution you found will work but would escape `HTML`

Answer (score 1):

After trying real  extra hard, I managed to solve the problem by concanenating an empty string (two single quotes) before the value to 'force' it to become a string. Here is the solution, it might save someone some hours of trial in future.

```
{% set arr = [] %}
{% setcontent pillars = 'Pillars' %}
{% for pillar in pillars %}
{% set str = ''~pillar.title %}
{% if str not in arr %}
{% set arr = arr|merge([str]) %}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{{ dump(arr) }}
```

Alternative solutions are welcome